# Okay to charge iPad 2 with 14 Watt charger?

Tags: ipad

My iPad 2 charger kinda burned. I bought a new charger from a shop near me. It is a 5v 2.8a (14 Watts) charger.

Is there any problem using that charger to charge my iPad 2?

Answer (score 1):

That's okay. As far I know, the actual charging power is selected by iPad. If the charger supports Apple 2.4A, iPad charges at 2.4A. Otherwise, a lower option will be chosen. 
As long as you bought a proper charger, bad ones are unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

All modern electronic is protected and self regulating and it will not suffer if you use bigger charger, AS LONG THE VOLTAGE IS CORRECT. (5 Volt)

Thus you will not damage it nor overcharge.

On the opposite end, if you use a smaller charger it wil just take much longer to charge.